# Android-Change Layout of view dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have some view in my activity :

```
for(int i=0;i<My_NewsGroup.size();i++)
    {
        View My_UpdateView=new View(MainActivity.this);
        My_UpdateView =LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
.....
    }
```

now i want to change layout of some view dynamically !

how can i do this ?

TnX
---------------------------------EDIT-------------------

```
LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent2);
    for(int i=0;i<My_NewsGroup.size();i++)
    {
        View My_UpdateView=new View(MainActivity.this);
        My_UpdateView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row2, null);

                     ....
                     .....          
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        ll2.addView(My_UpdateView,relativeParams);

        MyViewList.add(My_UpdateView);
    }
```

MyViewList is : List MyViewList=new ArrayList();

and then ! for example if i want to hide some View :

```
MyViewList.get(pos).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

but now i want to change layout for some view !

Comment: what do you mean by "change layout of some view dynamically"?

Comment: for example change R.layout.row2 to R.layout.row3

Comment: Why do you create a View and then inflate it from resource?

Comment: what do you do with My_UpdateView?

Comment: i want to have main layout with 10(and maybe more) Listview in each View !
every view have adapter for listviwe and because it i can't use adapter in main layout !(some problem..)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change view itself and reinflate it with different xml layout. You can change view's container content. Remove old view from ViewGroup and replace it with new one. Here is trivial example:

```
FrameLayout somelayout...
somelayout.removeView(viewYouWantToReplace);
somelayout.addView(inflator.inflate(R.layout.row2, somelayout, false));
```

Comment: i have too view in view's container ! i can't remove all View ! can i remove specified view and replace it with new view ?

Comment: Yeah you can, but it depends on container. Maybe you better wrap those views in ViewSwitcher.